# Codeigniter custom controller not loading anything

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, codeigniter-3

I have a `MY_Controller` that extends the `CI_Controller`, the `MY_Controller`
will hold all commom features of the app. A `Frontend_Controller` that extends the `MY_Controller`, this controller will hold all public related stuff. A `Admin_Controller` that will hold all administrative stuff, this controller also extends the `MY_Controller`, and some specfic controllers that extends `Frontend_Controller` or `Admin_Controller`.

I'm using a hook to autoload the controllers, here are my files:

**application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $data = array(); 

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->data['errors'] = array();
        $this->data['site_name'] = $this->config->item('site_name');
    }
}
```

**application/core/Frontend_Controller.php**

```
class Frontend_Controller extends MY_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump ('Hello');
    }
}
```

**application/controllers/Welcome.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends Frontend_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    public function index()
    {
        var_dump($this->data);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');

    }
}
```

My hook configuration

**application/hooks/App_controllers.php**

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

<?php
function load_app_controllers()
{
  spl_autoload_register('my_own_controllers');
}

function my_own_controllers($class)
{
  if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
  {
    if (is_readable(APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php'))
    {
      require_once(APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . '.php');
    }
  }
}
```

**application/config/hooks.php**

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hooks
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you define "hooks" to extend CI without hacking the core
| files.  Please see the user guide for info:
|
|   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html
|
*/

$hook['pre_system'][] = array(
  'class' => '',
  'function' => 'load_app_controllers',
  'filename' => 'App_controllers.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

In the `config.php` the hook is enabled `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;`

My problem is that the **Welcome** controller is loading a blank page, when I created the **MY_Controller** and tested on it, worked fine, but when I created the **Frontend_Controller** and tried only loaded a blank page.

Comment: did you check error_logs?

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the `App_controller.php` file, it had two `<?php` tags.